# View is not saved on screen orientation switch

Tags: android

The app is supposed to save the view which it draws on orientation change, but it doesn't.
Can anyone say where the problem is?

I don't get any error but when I change device orientation the view restarts without saving what I drew.

```
public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    conAdd();
}

public DrawingView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    conAdd();

}

private void conAdd() {
    paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(width);
    path = new Path();
    setOnTouchListener(this);
    setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
    Canvas canvasNew = new Canvas();
    canvasNew.setBitmap(bitmap);
    canvas = canvasNew;
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paint);
}

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        path.reset();
        path.moveTo(x, y);
        invalidate();
    }
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        if (Math.abs(x - lastX) > 4 || Math.abs(y - lastY) > 4) {
            path.quadTo(lastX, lastY, (lastX + x) / 2, (lastY + y) / 2);
            invalidate();

        }

    }

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        path.lineTo(x, y);

        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }

    lastX = x;
    lastY = y;
    return true;

}


 @Override
    protected Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
        Bundle inBox = new Bundle();
        inBox.putParcelable("draw", super.onSaveInstanceState());
        inBox.putParcelable("bitmap", bitmap);
        return super.onSaveInstanceState();

    }



 @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) 
    {
         if (state instanceof Bundle) {
              Bundle outBox = (Bundle) state;
              this.bitmap = outBox.getParcelable("bitmap");
              super.onRestoreInstanceState(outBox.getParcelable("draw"));
              return;
         }
         super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
    }
```

}

Comment: I also think your super.onRestoreInstanceState(state); should be BEFORE the other code

Comment: @QuintinBalsdon is correct, and also, where is your `onCreate()` and what not? The function that creates the view? you might be overriding the restored view..

Answer (score 0):

You need to manage configuration changes at runtime - it also took me a long time to find out where this was:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

**QUOTED:**
The following manifest code declares an activity that handles both the screen orientation change and keyboard availability change:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Comment: You don't need to override the orientation change functionality in order to persist your data state.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032173/configuration-changed-orientation-change-and-destroying-activities-is-this-t

Comment: It may be laborious on simple unprofessional apps to have to deal with the lifecycle of Activities being destroyed and recreated - this doesn't mean you should disable it. Loading alternate resources manually for screen sizes / orientations is just one of many examples which becomes a nightmare without this mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
```

?

Notive that while the *"orientation"* alone could fail to deliver it, adding the *"screenSize"* option will do the trick!

Comment: This is not a solution. you have to save the instance state!

Answer (score 0):

Your functions are incorrect:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    // Your code here

    // Call at the end
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    // Call at the start
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    // Your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning `super.onSaveInstanceState();` instead of returning your own bundle (`inBox`). So nothing is done with your saved data.